# Run Android on Android?

Tags: shell, command-line

We know it is possible to use chroot to run full Linux on android, also support Xserver (GUI).So, it should also be possible run another android on an exist android ? for example, using chroot to run android N on android 4.4. If it is true, we can run various version android without flash rom to device.So if anyone has any idea ?

Comment: How would the chrooted environment share the display, touchscreen, radio, and other I/O devices with the outside one?

Comment: Maybe we can "stop" the outside android( contains all services and managers,etc) and use the running kernel(which have loaded all available drivers) to "start" the inner android?  It's just my guess.